# Entity Framework 5.0 Inserts Duplicates on Add

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

Using EF 5.0, this always inserts two of the same record. I'm simply trying to create a single new record in my database. I've seen other articles about this, but am having a hard time piecing everything together, a re-code example would help me tremendously rather than posting a reference link. Thank you in advance.

```
 using (var context = new DBRegistrationEntities())
                    {
 Registration coNew = new Registration();
 coNew.user_id = userId;
 coNew.parent_id = userId.ToString();
 coNew.year = year;
 coNew.created = new Nullable<DateTime>(DateTime.Now);

 context.Registrations.Add(coNew);

 context.SaveChanges();
 }
```

Comment: Have you checked to ensure that you aren't executing this piece of code twice?

Comment: Looks OK, can you post some more code?

Comment: failedprogramming was correct, I had an inclusion for extra javascript. If you want to respond with an "answer" i'll mark it.


    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

failedprogramming was correct, I had an inclusion for extra javascript:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>

<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see problem in this part of code. It must be problem with model or/and context. But this code logic is strange to me. From where user_id comes from? From another table(Users?)? Why you don't use table relationships? Maybe second Registration is created while creating Entity for "Users"..